# Optimize count(*) with where is null clause on date column

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

In my database we store the audit information in the same table as the current record. So one table like product_customer has 4 columns product_id, customer_id, start_date, end_date with product_id, customer_id and start date as the primary key columns. Whenever we have to end a product association with a customer, we update end_date for that record and if a new product is purchased we insert a new record with corresponding customer and product id values, start_date as purchased date and end_date as NULL.

This table now has close to 60M records going back 20 years and around 65% of those records are audit information. I have suggested to move at least 15 years old data to an archive table but it is related to some retention policy so it has to be approved by a lot people.
My current Oracle DB version is 10G but it will be migrated to 12C in a couple of weeks.

There is a new requirement in which we need to return the count of customers associated with a particular product, but the problem is there are some products which have millions of customers so the query which I have written is taking a lot of time (sometimes 20 mins) to execute.

```
SELECT count(customer_id)
FROM product_customer
WHERE product_id = i_product_id AND end_date IS NULL;
```

Since we are migrating to Oracle 12c, is there a way to speed up this query (I read that B-Tree index does not index null values, a bitmap index does, but since there are very frequent DML statements running on this table, I don't think a bitmap index will work here).

Can you please help.

Comment: Please generate an explain plan for this query and append it to the question - this is an essential part of  any SQL optimization. Just run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR  SELECT count(customer_id) .... rest of your query` then `SELECT * FROM Table( DBMS_XPLAN>DIsplay )` and copy a result of last query and append it to the question.

Comment: Do you have enterprise edition with *partitioning option*? This is the solution you need!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the storing of the historical and actual version of the records in one table.

Basicaly the concept is fine as it makes easy to formulate the queries covering actual and history data. It also performs well with limited data, but at some scale you should take care, that the queries of *actual data* do not scan the *history data*

Oracle developed the *partitioning option* to address this problem.

You need to define a table with two partitions - one for the *actual data* the other for the *history*.

Use the `LIST` partitioning as follows:

```
create table prod_hist
(product_id int not null, 
customer_id int not null, 
start_date date, 
end_date date)
partition by list (end_date)
(PARTITION p_active values(NULL),
 PARTITION p_history values(default)
);
```

Important thing is, that after each change in customer product you need to *update* the `end_date` (from `null` to some readl date) - so you must *allow the row movement*

```
alter table prod_hist enable row movement;
```

Tehcnicall the row will be *deleted* from the active partition and inserted in the *history* partition.

Now your query will make a `full table scan` but **only on the active partitions**.

Example

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
SELECT count(customer_id)
FROM prod_hist
WHERE product_id = 1 AND end_date IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL'));

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |           |     1 |    22 |  1058  (23)| 00:00:13 |       |       |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |           |     1 |    22 |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION LIST SINGLE|           |   672 | 14784 |  1058  (23)| 00:00:13 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | PROD_HIST |   672 | 14784 |  1058  (23)| 00:00:13 |     1 |     1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("PRODUCT_ID"=TO_NUMBER(:I_PRODUCT_ID))
```

The active partition will have only 21M rows (35% from 60M), so this query should return in seconds.

If you are thinking **full scan is slow, I need an index**, this will most probably doesn't work here.

Remember that the **index access is your current problem** (at least by my 1 in 6 guess) and using the same index access will cut the elapsed time to 7 minutes (35% from 20).

**Why?** In most scenarios you have *millions of customers* but only *thousends of products*. This implies that you need to access a *large part of the active partition* to get all customers - and the full scan is better that index access.

Anyway if you have a different setupt with a *small number of customers* and a *large number of (individual) products* you may profit from the index

```
create index prod_hist_idx1 on prod_hist(product_id,customer_id) LOCAL;
```

Note that `LOCAL`  means you will use only the index on the active partition.
Also both *product_id* and *customer_id* is in the index, so you do not need to access the table at all.

Here the expected plan:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                |     1 |    22 |   741   (0)| 00:00:09 |       |       |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |                |     1 |    22 |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION LIST SINGLE|                |   672 | 14784 |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN    | PROD_HIST_IDX1 |   672 | 14784 |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("PRODUCT_ID"=TO_NUMBER(:I_PRODUCT_ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be able to take advantage of an index on `product_customer(product_id, end_date)`.

But, even scanning the table with 60 million rows should not take 20 minutes.  Other things may be interfering, such as:

- Other processes on the system locking records/tables.
- Using a view rather than table.

I will also point out that many systems -- and Oracle in particular -- that I've seen use an "infinite" end date rather than `NULL` in this case.  `DATE '4195-01-01'` seems popular; I don't know if that is a localism or more generally true.

Comment: The "20 minute" elapsed time suggests that the query does not *profit*, but *suffer* from the index access. Also the *popular* not NULL value in the `end_date` should be taken with care, as most probably it will cause A) a long running `UPDATE`  and B) comparable or even worst query performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following index:

```
create index product_customer_ai on product_customer(product_id, end_date) compress 1;
```

Since `product_id` is not null then there will be always an index entry for every table record even for those records where end_date is null.

Compression makes index more compact, it consumes less space on disk and is faster for reading.

Don't forget to gather statistics for a new index

```
begin
  dbms_stats.gather_index_stats(ownname => user,indname => 'PRODUCT_CUSTOMER_AI');
end;
/
```

Comment: This will work very fine for say a thousand customers with the particular product. But this will fail to be acceptable elasped time for 100K+ customers - independent of the index options.

Comment: Just give it a try. Should be much faster than a full table scan or PK index range scan (when PK first column is product_id). Not all clients have EE and partitioning option.